# Implementing Google Analytics on a Windows 8 Metro application

Tags: c#, windows-8, google-analytics, windows-store-apps

I'd like to implement Google Analytics tracking on a Windows 8 / Metro app.

There's no Windows SDK.

What would be the best way to do it in your opinion ?

Thanks, best regards

Geoffroy

Comment: Isn't Google Analytics for web?

Comment: For the JS based application the JavaScript API cannot be used https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/?

Comment: oups, sorry, the notification emails were in the spam box :(

Comment: First of all, vote here for MSAF support. http://msaf.codeplex.com/workitem/17880

Second, consider MSAF for WPF ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this something you are looking for?
Here is an article in our team blog on how we solve that issue:
http://dreamteam-mobile.com/blog/2012/08/windows-8-metro-apps-google-analytics/

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Comment: @AndrewBarber thanks! Missed that section, need to update my knowledge. Anyway I tried to share what I got

Answer (score 6):

[MarkedUp Analytics for Windows 8](https://markedup.com/register?utm_campaign=stackoverflowquestion) is another option for Windows 8 - it supports both WinJS and WinRT, and even works offline. It's currently free. (Disclaimer: I work on MarkedUp)

Comment: Looks like MarkedUp is not available anymore http://blog.markedup.com/2014/11/markedup-is-shutting-down/

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good one that with lots of features and activity:

https://github.com/AttackPattern/CSharpAnalytics

Answer (score 2):

If you're creating a new app, you will probably want to use the new [Google Analytics SDK for Windows 8 and Windows Phone](http://googleanalyticssdk.codeplex.com). Google recently had a major update to GA and added all kinds of snazzy features specifically for apps (vs. websites). Along with this change they scrapped the older UTM protocol and now require the newer measurement protocol for all apps. AFAIK, this SDK is the only one out there that supports the new measurement protocol thereby being the only one that works with new GA mobile app properties. Note: you can still use these other SDKs with existing GA properties or by fooling GA into thinking you're app is a website by providing a verifiable domain name.

Full disclosure: I wrote this SDK and created it for this very reason. It supports Win8 JS, Win8 Xaml, WP7, & WP8.

Comment: CSharpAnalytics also supports measurement protocol and has done since April 2013.

Comment: @Tim-Greenfield does it support WPF ?

Answer (score 2):

Many folks do not know that Microsoft gives **Telemetry SDK** http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh967768 as a nuget extension.

You can try it if GA is not a strong requirement.

Answer (score 1):

We ran into the same problem at Nascent, so we created an Open Source project for it.

Check out [Google Analytics for WinRT](http://gawinrt.codeplex.com/): A pretty simple but powerful Google Analytics client library for Windows Store apps.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer: I am the author for Gappalytics**

You should try [Gappalytics](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Gappalytics/) for code/UI event tracking, it is a very simple library which unlocks you a full potential of Google analytics.

It works better than mentioned before lib's because it can persist uniqueness of a user this way your data will not be skewed.

Comment: Hello Andreas, sorry for not including sample. And of course I have found a small bug that might have been preventing of using it in "Non-persistent" mode. Here is the source with sample https://github.com/Vasiliauskas/Gappalytics